# Excel TODAY() function in IF formula doesn't work properly

Tags: excel, function, formula

I have "Microsoft MonthView Control 6.0 (SP4)" component that enters the date to cell "D17" I want my function to compare today date to cells "D17" date and give certain message. So if date in cell "D17" is older than current date it will display "OFFER EXPIRED" message. In cell "D17" I currently have `1.10.2018`. I use formula `=IF(D17>TODAY();"OFFER EXPIRED";"")` but it doesn't work. I have tried different cell Formatting options with no success. Any ideas where the problem can hide?

Comment: Is `1.10.2018` being correctly recognized as a date?

Comment: Try `D17<TODAY()`

Comment: Try to format D17 in your comparison formula.

Comment: What's the result of formula auditing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
 =IF(1*SUBSTITUTE(D17;".";"/")>TODAY();"OFFER EXPIRED";"")
```

(Seeks to coerce Text `1.10.2018` into Number before making the comparison.)

Comment: Just tested it and actually ">" should be "<" in my case `=IF(1*SUBSTITUTE(D17;".";"/")<TODAY();"OFFER EXPIRED";"")` but the main point is that it works!!! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the date you have is in string format & in `dd.mm.yyyy` format. Use below code for the comparison:

```
=IF(DATE(
   RIGHT(D17,4),
   MID(D17,FIND(".",D17,1)+1, (
      FIND(".",D17,FIND(".",D17,1)+1)- 
      FIND(".",D17,1))-1),
   LEFT(D17,FIND(".",D17,1))
   )<TODAY(),
"OFFER EXPIRED","")
```

Comment: This formula is a bit extreme to deal with a simple issue such as this one. I won't downvote, but you should probably get more familiar with how Excel handles dates before positing an answer on this site in the future.